# Override behavior of std::locale constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, locale

I maintain an application in which many threads run on many (>200) cores.  We have to be very careful when using anything which uses std::locale as we suffer from lock contention on the global locale object when methods or operators use the locale object in any way.

In our application, the locale can be assumed to remain constant for the lifetime of the application (it will be taken from the system locale on startup and never change).

We can solve our performance problems punctually using local copies of the local when methods accept locale's as arguments, or by using alternatives when they don't, but it would be great if we could just tell the system that hey, the locale object is constant, you don't need to lock it -- so that whenever we use a new boost library, or a stringstream somwhere, we don't have to worry that we've created a lock contention on the locale.

Is there any way to accomplish such a thing?